# Не могу прикрепить Android Studio debugger к Android процессу

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не могу прикрепить Android debugger к Андроид процессу.
Когда захожу в выбрать процесс, там появляется мой телефон, но не появляются процессы, когда кликаю на "Show all processes" то процессы не появляются и кнопка "ОК" по прежнему не становится активной.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Android Monitor высвечивается "No debuggable Applications"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую в Терминале набрать "`adb kill-server`", но мне выдает: "adb" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

Пробовала делать Clean Project, Rebuild Project, а так же на самом телефоне отключить и включить USB debugging заново, но по прежнему без результатов.

Кто что посоветует?

П.С: я так же читала эту [статью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285999/cant-attach-android-studios-debugger-to-android-process) , но она мне не помогла так как терминал не воспринимает команду `adb kill-server`

Comment: вам необходимо поправить пути в вашей ОС, системе чтоб команды из под WIn терминала воспринимались.

Comment: Если вся проблема сводиться к тому что ты просто не можешь вызвать команду adb kill-server то решение проблемы лежит тут http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновила Android Studio до последней версии, проблема пропала.